# Multiple socket connections using asynchronous sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following code that makes a TCP socket connection to multiple end points as such:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listofIps = new List<string> { "192.168.168.193", "192.168.168.221" };
        foreach (var ip in listofIps)
        {
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 4001);
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                       SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sockets.Add(client);
            await client.ConnectTaskAsync(remoteEP);
            await ReadAsync(client);
        }
    }

    async Task ReadAsync(Socket s)
    {            
        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.SetBuffer(new byte[1024], 0, 1024);

        var awaitable = new SocketAwaitable(args);

        while (true)
        {
            await s.ReceiveAsync(awaitable);
            int bytesRead = args.BytesTransferred;
            if (bytesRead <= 0) break;

            var data = new ArraySegment<byte>(args.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            AppendLog("RX: " + data.DumpHex());
        }
    }

    public static string DumpHex(this ArraySegment<byte> data)
    {
        return string.Join(" ", data.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
    }

    public static Task ConnectTaskAsync(this Socket socket, EndPoint endpoint)
    {            
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(socket.BeginConnect, socket.EndConnect, endpoint, null);
    }
```

However, the loop doesn't iterate pass the first IP address, because of the await ReadAsync.

Qn 1) How do I modify this code such that it iterates through my whole list of IPs without "awaiting" for the data be received completely. Do I remove the `await` keyword from await `ReadAsync(client)`?
Qn 2) How do I modify this code such that it connects to all the IPs at once. (is this possible?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I modify this code such that it iterates through my whole list of IPs

Your code **will** iterate the whole list. But it will get to the second address only after it receives all data from the first address.

> How do I modify this code such that it connects to all the IPs at once.

If you encapsulate the code for a single address into a separate `async` method, you can then first call it for each address and then `await` all the returned `Task`s. Or you could use LINQ:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listOfIps = new List<string> { "192.168.168.193", "192.168.168.221" };
    await Task.WhenAll(listOfIps.Select(ip => ReadFromAddress(ip)));
}

private async Task ReadFromAddress(string address)
{
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 4001);
    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                               SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sockets.Add(client);
    await client.ConnectTaskAsync(remoteEP);
    await ReadAsync(client);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make my question clear. If I want the loop to continue to iterate regardless of whether data is finished receiving (because the data is being received continuously), all I need to do is to removed the await?

Comment: @The8thBit If you want to do that, use the code I posted, that's what it will do. Having a `Task` that's not `await`ed is dangerous, because it can hide exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the precaution! Great place to learn stuff like this :)