# How to wait for asynchronous callbacks to complete in C# .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a console program that needs to target .NET 3.5. In this program a range of internal IP addresses are being port scanned. I am checking 3 ports per IP address to see if they are open. I use the Socket.BeginConnect method which is asynchronous and has the callback function 'EndConnect' passed into it.

I am currently waiting for all the callbacks to complete by using Interlocked.Increment and Interlocked.Decrement on the 'waitingForResponses' integer variable and using a while loop to hold execution until waitingForResponses=0. Is this the proper way to wait for the async calls to complete?

```
class Program
{
    static bool stop = false;
    static List<string> activeIPs = new List<string>();
    static readonly object listLock = new object();
    static readonly object consoleLock = new object();
    static int consoleLineCount = 0;
    static int waitingForResponses = 0;
    static int maxQueriesAtOneTime = 60;
    static int[] tcp_ports = new int[] { 80, 8080, 22 }; 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        // enumerate the IP addresses
        int start = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { 1, 1, 168, 192 }, 0);
        int end = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { 20, 1, 168, 192 }, 0);
        List<IPAddress> addresses = new List<IPAddress>();
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
            addresses.Add(new IPAddress(new[] { bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0] }));
        }

        // start scans
        StartScan(addresses); // blocking - execution goes to next line after StartScan completes (but async calls to EndConnect may still be active)

        // Wait for all async callbacks to finish
        while (waitingForResponses > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        IncrementConsoleLineCount();
        Console.WriteLine("async callbacks have completed");

        IncrementConsoleLineCount();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }

    static void StartScan(List<IPAddress> ips)
    {
        //List<IPAddress> ips = o as List<IPAddress>;

        foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tcp_ports.Length; i++)
            {
                lock (consoleLock)
                {
                    IncrementConsoleLineCount();
                    Console.WriteLine("Scanning: " + ip.ToString() + ":" + tcp_ports[i]);
                }

                while (waitingForResponses >= maxQueriesAtOneTime) Thread.Sleep(0);
                if (stop) break;

                try
                {
                    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    s.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(ip, tcp_ports[i]), EndConnect, s); // asynchronous, callback=EndConnect
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref waitingForResponses);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    lock (consoleLock)
                    {
                        IncrementConsoleLineCount();
                        Console.WriteLine("StartScan Exception for: " + ip.ToString() + ":" + tcp_ports[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void EndConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        try
        {
            DecrementResponses();
            Socket s = ar.AsyncState as Socket;
            IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = s.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;

            s.EndConnect(ar); // ends a pending asynchronous connection request

            if (s.Connected)
            {
                lock (listLock)
                {
                    activeIPs.Add(remoteIPEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + remoteIPEndPoint.Port);
                }
                lock (consoleLock)
                {
                    IncrementConsoleLineCount();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to: " + remoteIPEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + remoteIPEndPoint.Port);
                }
                s.Disconnect(true); // Closes the socket connection and allows reuse of the socket
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }

    static void IncrementResponses()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref waitingForResponses);
    }

    static void DecrementResponses()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref waitingForResponses);
    }

    static void IncrementConsoleLineCount()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref consoleLineCount);
    }

    static void DecrementConsoleLineCount()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref consoleLineCount);
    } 

}
```

Comment: Does .Net 35. mean you can't use this technique?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486157/multiple-socket-connections-using-asynchronous-sockets

Comment: @SteveWellens Yes, the Task class came in .NET 4.